# Invalid Double.ToString() result in razor code generating javascript

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net-mvc, google-maps, razor

I use the following razor code to generate some javascript to produce markers on a Google map.

```
@foreach(Point point in Model.Points.Take(3))
{
    String longitude = point.Longitude.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    String latitude = point.Latitude.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    <text>
        var location = new google.maps.LatLng(@(longitude), @(latitude));
        bounds.extend(location);
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: location,
            map: map
        });
    </text>
}
```

In development, this correctly becomes:

```
var location = new google.maps.LatLng(52.2124273, 5.9545532);
bounds.extend(location);
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: location,
    map: map
});
```

However, on our production server, it becomes:

```
var location = new google.maps.LatLng(522124273000, 59545532000);
bounds.extend(location);
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: location,
    map: map
});
```

Which is producing just a grey Google map. What is causing this strange `ToString` behavior?

**edit**

The Point class is a custom class, not from a library. Here are the relevant parts:

```
public class Point
{
    private Double latitude;
    private Double longitude;

    public Double Latitude
    {
        get
        {
            return latitude;
        }
    }

    public Double Longitude
    {
        get
        {
            return longitude;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you check what the `DecimalSeparator` is on your production server?

Comment: What happens if you force the format? .ToString("#.############") ?

Comment: @chrfin Please note i am using CultureInfo.InvariantCulture as parameter to ToString in the start of the foreach. So de DecimalParameter is CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator which is a dot. I checked that on the server.

Comment: Assuming that Point is some sort of geography data type its possible the issue is one of projection / measurement rather than ToString on Doubles.  Is the measurement / projection on your data types consistent between the two environments.  You could check these with STSrid and AsTextZM functions. What Type is Point in your Model?

Comment: @AlexC added info about the Point class

Comment: @DaveBish With .ToString("#.############") i get exactly the same behavior :(

Comment: I would still tend to think that the data is different between the 2 environments.  What happens if you do change the line to String longitude = (point.Longitude - 0.1).ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture); to see where the strange behaviour is occurring in the different environments.

Comment: Have you checked the data in Model.Points to see if it holds the correct value 52.2..etc on the server or if it holds the incorrect 522..etc value (eg after you load the data, log it somewhere on the server side before you send it to the view)

Comment: In production, what happens if you do:

@(13.23232m.ToString()) ?

Comment: After some more investigation I think AlexC and JK. are right. The data is coming from an external API, I think both environments are parsing the JSON from there differently. I will look further into this tomorrow. Thanks for all your help.

Comment: nitpick: Prefer "string" and "double" not "String" and "Double".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JK and AlexC were right, see their comments on my question. The data was coming in wrong from the external API. Setting the global culture to en-US solved the issue.

I only do not understand one thing: I'm using a library which uses JSON.net, everywhere in the documentation it says the parsing is done with InvariantCulture. So I would think the global culture would not make a difference.

Answer (score 0):

1) Have you noticed that you have lat and lng the wrong way round in:

```
var location = new google.maps.LatLng(@(longitude), @(latitude));
```

2) I would check on production server that the data is correct - emit point.Longitude etc directly to the output as text somewhere to see if it is actually the ToString that is at fault and try (23.456).ToString() or similar too.

Comment: Ah, just looked at hidden comments and seen others have already suggested some of that.